# How browser maps the web response back to request?

Tags: http, browser, tcp

Say i make the web request(www.amazon.com) to amazon web server through browser. Browser makes the connection with Internet through Internet service providers.
Request reaches to amazon server which process it and send back the response. Two questions here :-

1. Does Amazon server makes new connection with internet to send the response back or incoming request(initiated by me) waits on socket till amazon process the response ?
2. Once my browser receives the response how does it map the response(sent from amazon) back to particular request . I believe there must be some unique identifier like
   requestId must be present in response through which browser must be mapping to request. Is that correct ?

Comment: You should study networking if you want to understand how things work. Trying to get your head around HTTP (and different versions too) without understanding TCP/IP is going to be tough.

Comment: @Kayaman i have gone through few networking articles. The question came up after read them. Actually i would like to go through in depth book about networking in future but at this point of time i am looking for high level understanding.

Comment: Your question number 2 is all about low level understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Does Amazon server makes new connection with internet to send the response back or incoming request(initiated by me) waits on socket
>      till amazon process the response ?

It uses the same connection. Most of the time it's not even possible to connect back to a web browser due to firewall restrictions or Network Address Translation (NAT).

> 2. Once my browser receives the request how does it map the response(sent from amazon) back to particular request . I believe
>      there must be some unique identifier like requestId must be present in
>      response through which browser must be mapping to request. Is that
>      correct ?

It receives the response on the same socket. So the socket is the identifier. If HTTP2 multiplexing is used, then each multiplexed stream has a stream identifier, which is used to map the response back to the request.

Comment: For first answer `It uses the same connection` I understand browser will use the same connection. But on server side,  the request is coming through internet (through sever ISP) . Will the http request on internet will wait on amazon server socket (which will ultimately call webserver) or web server will altogether create new response thread  which will ultimately be received on my browser machine where connection is still open ?  Sorry if i am  still not clear.

Comment: On second answer `It receives the response on the same socket. So the socket `, how the response coming back over internet knows which socket it needs to go ?

Comment: a TCP connection is initiated by the client(socket) on port number 80.

Comment: @Erwin Boldwidt can you please look at follow up query in comments ?

Comment: Your question seems to be in essence how TCP works, which is the underlying transport protocol for http. TCP connections are identified by ((local address, local port), (remote address, remote port)). The kernel of your OS keeps a table of this information mapped to your local socket. Whenever aan incoming IP packet arrives with protocol TCP, the above information is extracted from the packet and used to look up in this table.

Comment: Thanks Erwin it answers the socket mapping question. Can you please provide your thoughts on question in first comment too ?

Comment: I don't understand the comment. We don't know whether Amazon uses separate threads for responses or not, but that's besides the question about http and TCP. A web server is free to read the requests and generate the responses in any way that it likes, whether it uses threads, selectors, processes in a process pool or any other mechanism.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt say browser send two requests(assume ajax) at same time to  amazon server(same port number) They will be sent through different sockets. Now once my computer receives the response , how OS will know which requests maps to which socket as(port and remote address is same). Is there any other identifier specific to request also part from remote address, remote port ?

Comment: @user3198603 Every outgoing TCP connection also gets a "local port" number. Normally you don't see this, but with the "netstat" command on Unix you can find out. If you have two connections to port 80 on the same remote server, they will have different local *ports*. On a typical Linux server, the range of local ports is from 32768 to 61000.

Answer (score 4):

The client opens a TCP-connection to the server, sends an HTTP-request and the server sends the response using the same connection. So, the browser knows from the connection that the response belongs to a specific request. This applies to basic HTTP 1.

This has to be distinguished from the programming model of an AJAX web application which is asynchronous and not synchronous. The application does not actively wait for a response. It is instead triggered later when the response arrives. The connection handling described above is what happens "under the hood".

Back to the connection handling: There are optimizations of HTTP that make things more complicated. HTTP 1.1 has a feature called "keep alive" and HTTP 2 goes further into this direction. The idea is to send more data over a single TCP-connection because establishing a TCP-connection is expensive (-> three way handshake, slow start). So, multiple requests and responses are sent over a single TCP-connection. Your question arises again in case of this optimization. If e. g. there is a sequence of requests A, B and a sequence of corresponding responses B, A within a single HTTP-connection how does the browser know the request a response belongs to? HTTP 2 introduces the concept of streams ([RFC 7540, section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5)):

> A single HTTP/2 connection can contain multiple concurrently open
> streams, with either endpoint interleaving frames from multiple
> streams.

> The order in which frames are sent on a stream is significant.

> Streams are identified by an integer.

So, the stream identifier and the order within a stream can be used by the browser to find out the request a response belongs to.

HTTP 2 introduces another interesting feature which is called "push". The client can proactively send resources to the client that the client has not even requested. So, resources like e. g. images can be already sent when the HTML is requested avoiding another communication roundtrip.

Comment: For  `The client opens a TCP-connection to the server ....` I understand browser will use the same connection. But on server side, the request is coming through internet (through sever ISP) . Will the http request on internet will wait on amazon server socket (which will ultimately call webserver) or web server will altogether create new response thread which will ultimately be received on my browser machine where connection is still open ?

Comment: basically when you say `The client opens a TCP-connection to the server..`, actually this connection is connection to internet not to server and i that connection must be waiting till it gets the response back. So somehow there should be identifier in response so that it goes to right socket ?

Comment: The TCP-connection is normally an end-to-end connection between client and server. The server usually delegates a request to a thread so that a new request does not have to wait until all other requests are processed. The client and the server (it's thread) both have their sockets and each socket knows IP-address and port of the communication partner. So, let's say the browser (client) sends from port 50000 to port 80 of the server. The thread of the server sends the response back to port 50000 of client. IP-address and port together are like an address on an envelope.

Comment: TCP is a network protocol that provides a virtual connection between two hosts. The connection is defined by IP-address and port of both. "Connection" means that data arrive in same order as sent, no packages are lost and no packages are duplicated. The protocol itself uses IP which only cares for single packets which are delivered by routers. The virtual connection is like a cable that directly links the two hosts. The applications use sockets. The sockets care for the connection to work. The applications only use it. They only feed data into their end of the "line" and get data out of it.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP uses Transfer Control Protocol. This is how it happens- 
[image]

> 1. Does Amazon server makes new connection with internet to send the response back or incoming request(initiated by me) waits on socket till amazon process the response ?

No. Most browsers use HTTP 1.1 so the connection between client and server is established only once until closed (Persistent connection).

> 2. Once my browser receives the request how does it map the response(sent from amazon) back to particular request . I believe there must be some unique identifier like requestId must be present in response through which browser must be mapping to request. Is that correct ?

There is a protocol(HTTP) on how the messages are exchanged. HTTP dictates that responses must arrive in the order they were requested. So it goes like-

Request;Response;Request;Response;Request;Response;...

And there is also a specific format of HTTP request (from your browser- HTTP client) and HTTP response message (from amazon HTTP server). There are response status codes that let the browser know if their request has been succeeded, otherwise tell the errors.
A few sample codes-

[image]